# How To Ensure A Function Has Completed Before Calling Another - Promise Chaining Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I've built a set of functions that checks to see if there are any current notifications scheduled for iOS and if there are, I want to cancel them and reschedule them. The below logic will return if there are scheduled items, and if there are will begin the cancel and reschedule. The problem is, they all show to be successful and console logs to show this, but the reschedule function doesn't appear to be rescheduling them. Is there a way to ensure that they have been removed before trying to reschedule? My only guess is that I try to reschedule before it has completed removal.

```
if (isIOS){


      var getScheduled = function() {
        $cordovaLocalNotification.getAllScheduled().then(function (scheduledItems) { 
          $scope.scheduledContainer = scheduledItems;
          $scope.scheduledItems = scheduledItems;
            if($scope.scheduledItems.length < 1) {
              console.log('no previously scheduled items.')
              return;
            } else {
              cancelAll();
              console.log("there are items here.")
            }

        })
      }
      getScheduled();

      // If there are notifications, cancel and reschedule.

      var cancelAll = function() {
        console.log('we made it to the cancel function');
        // Cancell All
        $cordovaLocalNotification.cancelAll().then(function (result) {
            console.log('They Cancelled');
            rescheduleAll();
        });
      }

      var rescheduleAll = function() {
        //Reschedule All
            $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule($scope.scheduledItems).then(function() {
              console.log('Successfully Scheduled');

            });
      }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `finally` to execute functions after the promise is fullfilled:

```
var cancelAll = function() {
    console.log('we made it to the cancel function');
    // Cancell All
    $cordovaLocalNotification.cancelAll().then(function (result) {
        // This is the success handler
    }, function(err) {
        // This is the error handler
    }).finally(function() {
        console.log('They Cancelled');
        rescheduleAll();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use a .success promise and link the functions?

```
var function1 = function() {
     //do something
}.success(function () {
    function2();
}

var function2 = function () {
    //do something
}
```